# Equation with differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I am interested in finding conditions to impose over a one form $\alpha$ defined over a torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ to be sure that there is no function $g:\mathbb{T}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ solving the equation
$$ dg\wedge \alpha + gd\alpha = 0. $$

I have seen that if $\alpha$ is closed, then it is enough to take $g\equiv c\in\mathbb{R}$ to get the equation satisfied. So necessarily $d\alpha\neq 0$.

Is there some name for this kind of equations? How can I find some condition on $\alpha$?

Remark: I have that $g\not\equiv 0$ since I actually have $g=1/f$ for some function $f:\mathbb{T}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The issue will come with points where $\alpha = 0$ and yet $d\alpha\ne 0$. If $\alpha$ is nowhere zero, then locally there will always be solutions (although you may have global questions left). At any rate, if you take $\alpha = \sin(\pi x)\,dy$ on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, what happens?

Comment: I get $0=[(\partial_xg)\sin{(\pi x)}+\pi g\cos{(\pi x)}]dx\wedge dy$, and to solve it I can not divide by sine or cosine because they vanish at some point. How should I interpret your suggestion? @TedShifrin

Comment: My point is that if $\alpha(p)=0$, then for any function $g$, we have $(dg\wedge\alpha)(p)=0$. Thus, if $d\alpha(p)\ne 0$, we have no possible solution.

Comment: Ok sure. This means that since there is no function doing the required job at $p$, then I can say that there is no global solution. Right? @TedShifrin

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done. You can always choose $g$ to be the function $g(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{T}^2$.

Comment: Yes sure, sorry but I forgot to mention that $g\not\equiv 0$.